# проблема с flex-wrap + bootstrap3 на safari 9

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap4

В проект сделан на `bootstrap3` подключаю модуль из `bootstrap4 flex`. 
Исполльзую такую конструкцию

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      some text
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Суть в том, что свойство (`flex-wrap: wrap`) для класса `.row`, дает возможность выровнять по высоте блоки `.col-md-6`
На современных браузерах это отлично работает, и даже в ие11. 
Но в `safari 9.3 (ipad2)` и в хроме `< v43` , последний  блок `.col-md-6` переносится на следующую строку. 
Тестируется через сервис, потому поиграть с свойствами в инспекторе возможности нет.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема  заключалась в особенности класса .row в bootstrap3. 
Как известно, бутстрап задает стили для псевдоклассов before и after, устанавливая им свойство display: table; Таким образом предотвращает "схлопывание контейнера" .row , т.к для внутренних элементов задано обтекание float: left.

Но в новых брраузерах, содержимое псевдоклассов было безразмерное, 0x0 и данная проблема не всплывала.

Видимо в старых браузерах таблица имела обределенные габариты, или отступы (наверняка сказать не могу, т.к выводы делал по скринам, если у кого есть возможность посмотреть инспектор в данной версии браузера отпишите в коммент), что смещало первый элемент на 1px, в результате 2 блока с шириной в 50% уже не помещались в один ряд.

Проблему решил путем задания псевдоклассам ширину в 100%.