# Flex макет работает некорректно в Сафари

Tags: html, css3, bootstrap, flexbox, safari

Сделал на пробу макет, который работает как нужно в IE, FireFox и Chrome под Windows, даже под IE11.

Но рано обрадовался. В Safari под Mac и на iPad'е не работает промежуточный вариант с двумя колонками (ширина между 768 и 1199).

Я только начал знакомство с flex и пока вообще не представляю, в чем может быть проблема. Доступ к Mac'у у меня тоже пока ограничен, чтобы поиграться с вариантами.

Буду признателен, если кто-то сможет помочь.

```css
#section-tiles-home {
  margin: 15px;
}

#section-tiles-home .row {
  margin: 0;
}

#section-tiles-home [class^="col-"] {
  padding: 0;
}

#section-tiles-home .tile-img {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.tiles-col-1,
.tiles-col-2 {
  display: flex;
}

.tiles-col-2,
.tiles-col-3 {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.tiles-col-1>.tile-img {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.tiles-col-2 .tile-img:nth-child(1) {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

.tiles-col-2 .tile-img:nth-child(2) {
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.tiles-col-3>.row {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.tiles-col-3 .tile-img {
  height: 65vw;
}

.tile-img {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
}

.tile-img-text-container {
  align-self: stretch;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 15px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.tile-img-text-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.tile-img-text-container a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.tile-img-text-container .h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.tile-img-text-container .tile-img-text {
  display: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

.tile-img-text-container:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.tile-img-text-container:hover .h3 {
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}

.tile-img-text-container:hover .tile-img-text {
  animation: slideInUp .3s ease;
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .tiles-col-1 .tile-img {
    height: 100vw;
  }
  .tiles-col-2 .tile-img:nth-child(1) {
    height: 84vw;
  }
  .tiles-col-2 .tile-img:nth-child(2) {
    height: 105vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #section-tiles-home {
    margin: 7px;
  }
  #section-tiles-home>.row {
    display: flex;
  }
  #section-tiles-home .tile-img {
    margin: 7px;
  }
  .tiles-col-2 .tile-img {
    flex-basis: 0;
  }
  .tiles-col-3 .tile-img {
    height: 21vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  #section-tiles-home>.row {
    flex-flow: wrap;
  }
  .tiles-col-1 .tile-img {
    height: 66vw;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .tile-img-text-container .h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .tile-img-text-container .tile-img-text {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .tiles-col-3 .tile-img {
    height: 16vw;
  }
  .tile-img-text-container .h3 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  .tile-img-text-container .h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" integrity="sha256-j+P6EZJVrbXgwSR5Mx+eCS6FvP9Wq27MBRC/ogVriY0=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="section-tiles-home">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-8 tiles-col-1">
        <div class="tile-img" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/944/800?image=1063')">
          <div class="tile-img-text-container">
            <div class="h3">Tile 1</div>
            <div class="tile-img-text">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img class="media-object" src="https://picsum.photos/70/70?image=1074" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img class="media-object" src="https://picsum.photos/70/70?image=1074" alt="">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                </div>
              </div>
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusamus adipisci distinctio ducimus ipsa modi neque quia quod rerum vel! Culpa nihil nisi numquam perspiciatis quam quod reiciendis repellat saepe? Pariatur!
              </p>
              <a href="#">Link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 tiles-col-2">
        <div class="tile-img" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/466/314?image=1041')">
          <div class="tile-img-text-container">
            <div class="h3">Tile 2</div>
            <div class="tile-img-text">
              <a href="#">Link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile-img" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/469/477?image=1044')">
          <div class="tile-img-text-container">
            <div class="h3">Tile 3</div>
            <div class="tile-img-text">
              <a href="#">Link</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 tiles-col-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="tile-img" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/466/480?image=1067')">
              <div class="tile-img-text-container">
                <div class="h3">Tile 4</div>
                <div class="tile-img-text">
                  <a href="#">Link</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="tile-img" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/469/317?image=1061')">
              <div class="tile-img-text-container">
                <div class="h3">Tile 5</div>
                <div class="tile-img-text">
                  <a href="#">Link</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="tile-img" style="background-image:url('https://picsum.photos/469/477?image=1057')">
              <div class="tile-img-text-container">
                <div class="h3">Tile 6</div>
                <div class="tile-img-text">
                  <a href="#">Link</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хм, кажется нашлось решение. На решение натолкнул этот вопрос/ответ тёзки:
[проблема с flex-wrap + bootstrap3 на safari 9](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819373/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-flex-wrap-bootstrap3-%d0%bd%d0%b0-safari-9)

Добавил в CSS это и все заработало:

```
#section-tiles-home .row:after,
#section-tiles-home .row:before {
    display: inherit;
}
```